# Has the testnet been reset with a new genesis block?

Tags: testnet

I mined some testnet monero using version 0.10.0.0  a few months ago. Now, when I restore from my testnet wallet seed with version  0.10.1.0, it says 0 balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no new genesis block. However, there was a massive (about two months, I think) reorg when the ringct implementation switched from ASNL to Borromean signatures for the range proofs.

Comment: Would the change in ringct implementation affect my testnet balance?

Comment: The reorg would, if what you mined was in the reorganized part of the chain. Which was a couple months before the switch, which was... early december. So if you mined between early october and early december, your coinbases were reorged away. The exact cutoff block height is 801219.